# Searching by location

Tags: select-by-location, geolocation, service-recommendations

I need an advice for a service.

On our website we have a search for events. Users are especially interested in the location of event so they use that filter a lot but the problem is that in our database we have sometimes England sometimes UK so we cannot provide them the information they are looking for.

Do you have any experience with this? We store the location of events in plain text (e.g. "London, UK") and we would like to use something more sophisticated. So in the future user will be able to search for events in London and in 100km radius for example. (so we show them also the events in Oxford.)

I have no experience with GEO location so maybe it's something simple maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either a *Thesaurus* that maps your search-terms to general terms (e.g. `UK`-->`England`, `United Kingdom` --> `England`, ...) or a *gazetteer*-service that does the same but also provides functionalties to search by geo-location and get the the name stored within that database that relates to that location (e.g. `(60, 0)` --> `London`).

Both are available on the web via open services, e.g. http://www.gazetteer.org.uk/